# Angular -- ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. (Nested FormArray)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

**Preface**: I realize this may be a duplicate, but having read the detailed explanation of the error found [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) I still do not understand how my code would be invalidating the dirty checking performed in change detection.

I have a FormGroup that contains a FormArray. I would like to nest the FormArray into a child component since it contains quite a bit of it's own specific business logic.

When I load the component in the browser, and when I run unit tests I receive the following exception:

```
ParentComponentA.html:2 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
    at viewDebugError (core.es5.js:8426)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.es5.js:8404)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.es5.js:8568)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.es5.js:12448)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.es5.js:12414)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.es5.js:13191)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.es5.js:13131)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ParentComponentA.html:2)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13113)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.es5.js:1223
```

**Parent Component A:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-component-a',
  templateUrl: './parent-component-a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent-component-a.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponentA implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  activeMediaViewport: string; // Should match a value of MaterialMediaQueries enum
  mediaWatcher: Subscription;
  parentForm: FormGroup;
  childComponentDisplayMode: number; // Should match a value of ComponentDisplayModes enum

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private mediaQueryService: ObservableMedia) {
    const prepareComponentBFormControl = (): FormGroup => {
      return formBuilder.group({
        'code': '',
        'weight': '',
        'length': '',
        'width': '',
        'height': '',
      });
    };

    const prepareParentForm = (): FormGroup => {
      return formBuilder.group({
        // ... omitted other properties
        'childComponentList': formBuilder.array([prepareComponentBFormControl()])
      });
    };

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeWatchers();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.mediaWatcher.unsubscribe();
  }

  /**
   * Sets intervals and watchers that span the entire lifecycle of the component and captures their results to be used for deregistration.
   */
  private initializeWatchers(): void {
    this.mediaWatcher = this.mediaQueryService
      .subscribe(mediaChange => {
        this.activeMediaViewport = mediaChange.mqAlias;
        this.childComponentDisplayMode = this.calculateComponentDisplayMode(this.activeMediaViewport);
      });
  }
}
```

*component A HTML markup attributes*

```
<child-component-b [displayMode]="childComponentDisplayMode"
                   [nestedFormList]="childComponentList">
</child-component-b>
```

**Child Component B:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component-b',
  templateUrl: './child-component-b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component-b.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponentB implements OnInit {

  @Input() displayMode: number; // Should match a value of ComponentDisplayModes enum
  @Input() nestedFormList: FormArray;

  mobileDisplays: Array<number>;
  largeDisplays: Array<number>;
  numberOfRowsToAdd: FormControl;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.mobileDisplays = [ComponentDisplayModes.TABLET_PORTRAIT, ComponentDisplayModes.PHONE_LANDSCAPE, ComponentDisplayModes.PHONE_PORTRAIT];
    this.largeDisplays = [ComponentDisplayModes.DESKTOP, ComponentDisplayModes.TABLET_LANDSCAPE];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // including in this SO post since it references the @Input property
    this.numberOfRowsToAdd = new FormControl(this.defaultRowsToAdd, this.addBuisnessLogicValidator(this.nestedFormList)); 
  }

  private addBuisnessLogicValidator(nestedFormListRef: FormArray): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    const rowsRemaining = maxLinesAllowed - nestedFormListRef.length;
    const rowsToAdd = control.value;
    const isInvalid = isNaN(parseInt(rowsToAdd, 10)) || rowsToAdd < 0 || rowsToAdd > rowsRemaining;
    return isInvalid ? {'invalidRowCount': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
```

}
    }

*component B HTML markup attributes*

```
<div *ngFor="let listItem of nestedFormList.controls; index as index"
     [formGroup]="listItem">
</div>
```

I think maybe using *ngFor in the child component may "dirty" the view's value during change detection?

Comment: read [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: Can you create a plunker with your problem?

Comment: I have read that article @AngularInDepth.com - that's what I linked in my OP. I still don't understand what I'm doing in this scenario that would be updating anything to cause the exception. yurzi I'll try to put it into a plunker when I have more time, thanks.

Comment: @rawkfist0215, yeah, try to create a plunker then

Comment: I was able to find the solution. Creating the plunkr helped me isolate potential problem points and narrow down the cause. Thank you both for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was operator error (go figure). I found out that this exception was thrown, because I had an artifact "required" attribute defined on the HTML `<input>` element without stating that it was required in the FormControl validator defintion using Angular's `Validators.required` static method.

Having them defined in one place but not the other caused the value to change between the first and second Change Detection routines.

So...

```
          <input mdInput
               formControlName="weight"
               placeholder="Weight"
               type="text"
               aria-label="weight"
               maxlength="6"
               required>
```

The "required" and "maxlength" attributes need removed from the template and placed in the FormGroup definition, i.e.

```
const prepareComponentBFormControl = (): FormGroup => {
      return formBuilder.group({
        'code': '',
        'weight': ['', Validators.required, Validators.maxlength(6)],
        'length': '',
        'width': '',
        'height': '',
      });
    };
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked for me as well. 

I also had a nested `FormArray` in a `FormGroup`, which interacted with an `<input>` that had a `required` attribute. Once I removed the `required` attribute, this error went away -- I presume I can reintroduce once I add the `Validator.required` to match.