# How to troubleshoot ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Previous value for 'ng-valid': 'true'. Current value: 'false'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Can someone help me troubleshoot this.  It happens when the form becomes valid, but then I go back and init this component (push a new value in the FormArray (from zero items)).  How do I figure out which property ng-valid is triggering on?  Is it the array? individual element in array? or the entire formgroup?

I've tried `ngAfterContentChecked() { this.cdr.detectChanges(); }` and `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, and calling `this.cdr.detectChanges()` after a push call. Still doesn't work.  It's weird because it only happens the first time the form is valid, and then I add a an element.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-other-conditions',
  templateUrl: './list-other-conditions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../survey-pmhx.component.scss']
})

export class ListOtherConditionsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input()
  formGroup!: FormGroup

  @Input()
  arrayName!: string

  get formArray():FormArray {
    return this.formGroup!.get(this.arrayName)! as FormArray
  }

  addItem() {
    this.formArray.push(this.initItem())
  }
  removeItem(i:number) {
    this.formArray.removeAt(i)
    if (this.formArray.length === 0)
      this.formArray.push(this.initItem())
  }

  public initItem = () : FormGroup =>
    this.fb.group({
      diagnosis: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
      year: this.fb.control(null, [Validators.required, CustomValidators.pastYear])
    })

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private readonly cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.formArray.length === 0)
      this.addItem();
  }
  }


}
```

Comment: how is your code
  formGroup and arrayName? is something like form: FormGroup = this.fb.group ({
    arrayName: this.fb.array ([])
  }); y <form [formGroup] = "form">
  <div formArrayName = "arrayName">
    <div * ngFor = "let some of arrayName.controls">
      <input />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

Comment: Yep exactly, it's in the parent component`<form [formGroup]="form"` `let myform = this.fb.group({ list: this.fb.array([]))})`  And this child component is called `<app-list-other-conditions [formGroup]="myform" arrayName="list"></...`

Comment: So I don't see why you define arrayName !: string since it is an array, you could upload the code of the parent component and the template so I try to execute it and see your problem.

Comment: while it may be useful to you https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-formarray-validation

Comment: I define arrayName because it's needed for template building (easier to use formArrayName).

Comment: I found that the error can occur if there is a validation in the template and a different one in the code, a characteristic if that is why it is not produced in production

Comment: https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

Comment: https://medium.com/beingcoders/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-angular-basics-94d01271016f

Comment: If you upload the code of the temple it seems to me it will be easier for anyone to answer you

Answer (score 0):

> I repeated the logic of your code starting a FormGroup in the child
> component, although I consider it unnecessary and it is not giving me
> an error, I also create a child FormGroup and start the view of the
> child component which does not seem necessary but does not cause an
> error so Therefore, the error must be when injecting the FormArray as
> a string although it is also possible to inject it as a string to the
> value of the FormArray, you are not doing it correctly

[code in github use path about](https://github.com/nestdanchia/FormArray/blob/main/src/app/about/empleados/team-management.component.ts)

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TeamManagementService } from '../empleados/team-management.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-other-condition',
  templateUrl: './list-other-condition.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-other-condition.component.css']
})
export class ListOtherConditionComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  formGroup!:FormGroup
  
  @Input()
  employees!:  FormArray
  allSkills!: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(private fbchild: FormBuilder,private teamMngService: TeamManagementService, private fb: FormBuilder, private readonly cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){
    this.allSkills = this.teamMngService.getSkills()
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.employees.length === 0)
    this.addEmployee();

  }
  get age() { return this.employees.get('age'); }

  get empName() { return this.employees.get('empName'); }
 
    addEmployee() {
        let fg = this.createEmpFormGroup();
        this.employees.push(fg);
    }
  deleteEmployee(idx: number) {
        this.employees.removeAt(idx);
    }
  
  public errorHandling = (control: string, error: string) => {
    return this.formGroup.controls[control].hasError(error);
  }

  createEmpFormGroup() {
        return this.fb.group({
            //empName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      empName:this.fbchild.control(null, Validators.required),
        //  age: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.min(21)]],
    age:this.fbchild.control(null, [Validators.required,Validators.min(21)]),
        //  skill: ['', [Validators.required]],
    skill:this.fbchild.control(null, Validators.required),
        })}

}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<p>list-other-condition works!</p>
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div formArrayName="employees">
        <div *ngFor="let emp of employees.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i" class="employee">
            
          <mat-label>Employee : {{i + 1}}</mat-label>
       
            <mat-label>Name :</mat-label> 
            <mat-form-field >
            <input matInput formControlName="empName">
            
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-error *ngIf="employees.controls[i].get('empName')?.errors?.required">empName is required</mat-error>
            
            
            
          Age :
            <mat-form-field >
            <input matInput formControlName="age">
            
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-error   *ngIf="employees.controls[i].get('age')?.errors?.required"> Age required.</mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="employees.controls[i].get('age')?.errors?.min">
           
            Minimum age is 21.
        
</mat-error>


            
            
             
             
             
            
           

          <h2>Skill :</h2>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Your skill</mat-label>
            <mat-select  formControlName="skill"required>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let skill of allSkills | async" [value]="skill.name" >
                {{ skill.displayName }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            
            
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-error
              *ngIf="employees.controls[i].get('skill')?.errors?.required"
             
              >You must make a selection </mat-error>
         <p>
            <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="deleteEmployee(i)">Delete</button>
          </p> 
        
      </div>
      <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="addEmployee()">Add More Employee</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

```html
<h3>Create New Team</h3>
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Crear Team</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    
  <form [formGroup]="teamForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
    
   <h2>Team Name :</h2> 
      <mat-form-field >
      <input matInput formControlName="teamName">
     
      </mat-form-field>
    <mat-error>  
      <span *ngIf="!teamName?.valid && teamName?.touched">Please enter Team Name !!!</span>  
  </mat-error>  
    

  
    
    <h2>Employees in Team:</h2>
  
     
 
  
  
      <app-list-other-condition [formGroup]="teamForm" [employees]="employees" ></app-list-other-condition>
      <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!teamForm.valid">SUBMIT</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
  </form>
</mat-card-content>
  
</mat-card>
<p>Form Status: {{ teamForm.status }}</p>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, Validators, FormBuilder, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { TeamManagementService } from './team-management.service';
import { Team } from './team';
//import { Employee } from './employee';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-team',
    templateUrl: './team-management.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./team-management.component.css']

})

export class TeamManagementComponent implements OnInit {
    teamForm = {} as FormGroup;
    //isValidFormSubmitted: boolean | null = null;
    allSkills: Observable<any[]>;
    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private teamMngService: TeamManagementService) {
        this.allSkills = this.teamMngService.getSkills();
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.teamForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            teamName: ['', Validators.required],
            employees: this.formBuilder.array([])
                
        });
    }
    // teamForm.teamName.errors
    get formControls() { return this.teamForm.controls; }
    get teamName() {
        return this.teamForm.get('teamName');
    }
    get employees(): FormArray {
        return this.teamForm.get('employees') as FormArray;
    }
    //[disabled]="!teamForm.valid"
    onFormSubmit() {
        
    
    
        if (this.teamForm.valid) {
            console.log('form submitted');
          }
        let team: Team = this.teamForm.value;
        this.teamMngService.saveTeam(team);
        this.teamForm.reset();
    }
    resetTeamForm() {
        this.teamForm.reset();
    }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { Team } from './team';

const ALL_SKILLS = [
    { name: 'Java', displayName: 'Java' },
    { name: 'Angular', displayName: 'Angular' },
    { name: 'Dot Net', displayName: 'Dot Net' }
];

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TeamManagementService {
    getSkills() {
        return of(ALL_SKILLS);
    }
    saveTeam(team: Team) {
        console.log('------------TEAM------------');
        console.log('Team Name: ' + team.teamName);
        console.log('----- Employee Details -----');
        for (let emp of team.employees) {
            console.log('Emp Name: ' + emp.empName);
            console.log('Emp age: ' + emp.age);
            console.log('Emp Skill: ' + emp.skill);
            console.log('-------------------');
        }
    }
}
```

your problem must be a conceptual error in

> the communication between the parent component and the child
>
> It may be that The control becomes invalid because it does not provide
> the initial value and specifies a required validator as the code of parent component  does
> not have impossible to know or also the following reasons

`FormArray` provides a way to collect the dynamically created
forms in one place. You can access each of the forms using the index and the controls inside it

```
<app-list-other-conditions [formGroup]="myform" [arrayName]="list">
and child

@Input()
arrayName!:  FormArray
```

> So it can be accessed correctly different from how you defined
> Although it is also possible to inject it as a string to the FormArray
> value, you should not be doing it correctly but

```
@Input ()
arrayName !: string
```

I have a draft of its use in the folder employees files file `team-management.component.ts`
[draft `FormArray`](https://github.com/nestdanchia/FormArray/blob/main/src/app/about/empleados/team-management.component.ts)

> error NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked This is a
> cautionary mechanism put in place to prevent inconsistencies between
> model data and UI so that erroneous or old data are not shown to a
> user on the page. This catches errors where the view is left in an
> inconsistent state.  This can occur, for example, if a method or
> getter returns a different value each time it is called, or if a child
> component changes values on its parent. If either of these occur, this
> is a sign that change detection is not stabilized. Angular throws the
> error to ensure data is always reflected correctly in the view, which
> prevents  erratic UI behavior or a possible infinite loop. To make
> sure not to produce the error define  the FormArray in the parent
> component  and send it to the child component as FormArray
> [error Expression Changed](http://%20https://angular.io/errors/NG0100)
>
> *there can always be code errors as well as shown in this answer in the
> forum [error required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46288008/8957405)*